# How can I place a word in the center of a splash screen in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

```
[Activity(Label = "Test", Theme = "@style/LaunchTheme", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity

<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Here's my current splash screen in file splash_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
                android:tileMode="disabled"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What I would like to do is instead of the logo I would like to place the word "Test" so it appears in white text in the center, vertically and horizontally.

Could anyone give any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: Can I see how your splash screen XML looks like to give you a quick fix?

Comment: The splash screen is the XML in the question.   I want to remove the logo and replace with the word "Test" in the center.

Comment: That's a layered list are you using a theme directly as your splash screen?

Comment: I updated the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just you a text View and make its align center if you are use relative layout use

```
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

constraint layout use this

```
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

and if you are using linear layout use layout_gravity=center

Comment: Thanks but to make it complete.  Could you add these to the question code so I will know where to go.  Sorry but I'm not an Android person and don't know even how to add a label.  Thanks

Comment: I did.  It's in the question

Answer (score 0):

Splash Screen only accepts Drawable resources, that is, if you want to put text into this screen, you'll also need to rasterize your text. After the is ready, you can put it under your project's Resources/Drawable folder, and use it in splash_screen.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/yourImageName"
                android:tileMode="disabled"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please use your favorite search engine with keyword as 'How to Add a Splash Screen—The Right Way' to find proper resources for your question.